# Sqlite Move Database to Memory in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, database-connection

How can I move an sqlite disk database to memory in C# ?

I need to open a database from disk to an in-memory database for faster operations and when it finishes the work then save it back to file.

The disk database is an empty database, I want to transfer the data from a List to the memory database and use this to sort very large data which kills the List.Sort function. After the data is sorted I don't need the database anymore.

Comment: Don't do that. Increase the [cache size](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size), and [memory map the database](https://www.sqlite.org/mmap.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot [do that](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/inmemorydb.html). And I do not recommend that, Why don't you just increase the cache size?

> An SQLite database is normally stored in a single ordinary disk file.
>   However, in certain circumstances, the database might be stored in
>   memory.
>
> The most common way to force an SQLite database to exist purely in
>   memory is to open the database using the special filename ":memory:".
>   In other words, instead of passing the name of a real disk file into
>   one of the sqlite3_open(), sqlite3_open16(), or sqlite3_open_v2()
>   functions, pass in the string ":memory:". For example:

And every connection to `SQlite` creates a seperated new database.

> rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db); When this is done, no disk file is
>   opened. Instead, a new database is created purely in memory. The
>   database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed.
>   Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two
>   database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two
>   independent in-memory databases.

If you are going to implement such a thing, there are not any official way to do it! But you can:

1. Open a new in-memory db
2. Copy all data from file db to memory
3. Compare and merge new/deleted/updated data from memory to disk

Here is code in C language as an example for opening a `SQLite` file as an `in-memory`:

https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@mailinglists.sqlite.org/msg15929.html

Comment: There actually are several ways to do it (Though a particular language's sqlite bindings might not export the appropriate C API, and at least one of them requires sqlite to be compiled with a specific non-default option, so they're not very portable unless using C or C++ where you can include the sqlite source file directly in your project). It is, however, yes, a bad idea, especially if you want changes to persist in the on-disk copy.

Comment: thanks! I don't know if the cache will help with adding 1.5 million records, then sorting it. (select order by). The disk database is just an empty database, I want to load it into memory then add data from List then sort the data and discard the database.